# Checking Solution: For an integer $k \geq 2$, $f(k)$ is the number of positive integers $n$ such that $n|(n-1)!+k$. Compute $\sum^{100}_{r=2} f(r)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I'm looking for someone to confirm my solution to the following question:

Question: For a positive integer $k \geq 2$, let $f(k)$ be the number of positive integers $n$ such that $n|(n-1)!+k$. Compute $$\sum^{100}_{r=2} f(r)$$

I started by observing that:

- (1) If $n=2$, then $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$.
- (2) If $n=3$, then $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$.
- (3) If $n=4$, then $(n-1)! \equiv -2 \pmod{n}$.
- (4) If $n \geq 5$ is prime, then $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$.
- (5) If $n \geq 5$ is composite, then $(n-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

We can rewrite the condition $n|(n-1)!+k$ as $$(n-1)! \equiv -k \pmod{n}$$

Now, we do casework by finding the number of possible $k$ for each $n$.

(1) $-k \equiv -1 \pmod{2}$, yielding $k=3,5,7,\cdots,99$ for a total of $49$ possibilities.

(2) $-k \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, yielding $k=4,7,10,\cdots,100$ for a total of $33$ possibilities.

(3) $-k \equiv -2 \pmod{4}$, yielding $k=2,6,10,\cdots,98$ for a total of $25$ possibilities.

(4) $-k \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$, meaning $n$ divides $k-1$. This yields a total of $$\sum_{k \in S_1} \lfloor \frac{99}{k} \rfloor=87$$ possibilities, where $S_1$ is the set of all primes from $5$ to $97$, both inclusive.

(5) $-k \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, meaning $n$ divides $k$. This yields a total of $$\sum_{k \in S_2} \lfloor \frac{100}{k} \rfloor=186$$ possibilities, where $S_2$ is the set of all composite numbers from $6$ to $100$, both inclusive.

Adding all the cases together, $$\sum^{100}_{r=2} f(r)=49+33+25+87+186=\boxed{380}$$